# Better error messages upon critical errors - HTTP Error 500

Tags: errors, wp-config

I had an error in a custom class I've made, where this was the error:

```
private function someFunction(): void { // Returns void
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return true; // <- Returns a value, when the function is set to void
}
```

In my `wp-config.php` I have these lines added:

```php
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
```

If I add this: `define( 'WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER', true );` to my `wp-config.php`-file, then I get a HTTP ERROR 500.

But I still got an the message:

> There has been a critical error on this website.

---

How do I get better error messages for situations like these?

I mean... How difficult can it be to tell me where an error like this is in the code. #firstworldproblems

Answer (score 1):

WordPress error handling is pretty good, but you do need to do a little work to shape this to your needs:

I can tell you that the most simple set-up I know is to log errors to the wp-content/debug.log file - using the following set-up in wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
define( 'WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER', true );
```

You can also extend the information in the log using xdebug - https://xdebug.org/ - but it's not essential.

This should give you type, line and reason for all PHP error, like:

```
[30-Dec-2020 19:54:39 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'an' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in C:\xampp\htdocs\file.php on line 10
```

Comment: Hmm... It is not possible to do something that makes the error avaible in the frontend? So I don't have to download the log from the server and find the appropriate datestamp to find the error?

Comment: Errors should be private - you don't really want everyone to know  why your site is failing - and they should really be debugged locally.. where you don't need to FTP into the file..